How to use the token from flutter pay package with the Cybersource api for Google Pay & Apple Pay?
im struggling to understand how to use the card token generated by the flutter pay package in conjunction with the cybersource api, I managed to understand how to use it with stripe api but cybersource api documentation is to hard to understand.

I want to do the same thing, is there a solution?
